# for statement does not loop - android

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop

I'm breaking the for loop after the first iteration. I am aware it is not good practice to do so but I am not sure how to fix this. 
I get the message "for statement does not loop". I am using android studio IDE.

```
List<PriceWithCurrency> commercialPrices = purchaseLineItem.getProduct().getCommercialPrices();
CrewSalesRecord crewSalesRecord =
        new CrewSalesRecord(
                purchase.getEmployeeIdentifier(),
                purchaseLineItem.getQuantity());
                crewSalesRecords.add(crewSalesRecord);

for (PriceWithCurrency currency : commercialPrices) {
    ProductData purchaseData = new ProductData(
            purchaseLineItem.getProduct().getProductId(),
            purchaseLineItem.getProduct().getShortDescription(),
            purchaseLineItem.getQuantity(),
            crewSalesRecords, currency.getPrice());
            uncombinedProductDataList.add(purchaseData);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Your `break` exits the `for` loop on the first pass through.

Comment: Why don't you just `get` the first element in the list, call it `currency` and remove the loop? Why do you even have a loop if you aren't looping?

Comment: is that message an error?

Comment: Its just a warning as Studio does static code analysis. Since its deliberate, you can ignore it.

Comment: No, I don't get any errors. It was just a pop up message. @bradimus , True, It always exists after the first pass. How can I do this without looping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that's a compiler warning, not an error. However, if you're going to break your loop after the first iteration anyway, why won't you just fetch the first item in the list instead of looping?

Example:

```
for (PriceWithCurrency currency : commercialPrices) {
     ProductData purchaseData = new ProductData(purchaseLineItem.getProduct().getProductId(),
               purchaseLineItem.getProduct().getShortDescription(), purchaseLineItem.getQuantity(),
crewSalesRecords, currency.getPrice());
     uncombinedProductDataList.add(purchaseData);
     break;
}
```

Becomes

```
PriceWithCurrency firstCurrency = commercialPrices.get(0);
ProductData purchaseData = new ProductData(purchaseLineItem.getProduct().getProductId(),
    purchaseLineItem.getProduct().getShortDescription(), purchaseLineItem.getQuantity(),
    crewSalesRecords, firstCurrency.getPrice());
uncombinedProductDataList.add(purchaseData);
```